# Gitlab CI Pipeline status using url

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to get the status information for the latest gitlab pipeline using the url

```
https://gitlab.test-server.ag/qs/e2e/pipelines
```

I have used somthing like

```
https://gitlab.test-server.ag/qs/e2e/pipelines/latest/status
```

But it is deprecated. Any ideas how to get this using the url or even using rest api?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. There is an issue [open](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/39099) asking this feature but still in the backlog.